# Better string manipulation code

Tags: java

I'm looking for an efficient (one line) string manipulation code to achieve this, regex probably.
I have a string, for example, "Calvin" and I need to convert this to "/C/a/l/Calvin".
i.e. take first three characters, separate them using '/' and later append the original string.

This is the code I've come up with and its working fine, just looking for a better one.

```
String first = StringUtils.substring(prodName, 0, 1);
String second = StringUtils.substring(prodName, 1, 2);
String third = StringUtils.substring(prodName, 2, 3);

String prodPath = path + "/" + first + "/" + second + "/" + third + "/" + prodName + "/" ;
```

Comment: This is easily readable - Maybe use StringBuilder instead though

Comment: A single line of code will be terse, but using a regex might not be the most CPU efficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
prodName.replaceAll("^(.)(.)(.).*", "/$1/$2/$3/$0")
```

Comment: Don't need the leading `^`. Also, you dropped the leading `path` and trailing `/` from the result.

Comment: @Andreas I was addressing OP's statement *I have a string eg "Calvin" and i need to convert this to "/C/a/l/Calvin".* The rest can be deduced easily enough. As for the `^`, I'll have to take your word for it since I'm not at a computer.

Comment: `(.)(.)` there is a certain beauty to your answer

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's the martian from Total Recall. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

What is the point of `StringUtils.substring(prodName, 0, 1)` when the built-in `prodName.substring(0, 1)` will do the same thing??

Anyway, *assuming* `prodName` is always at least 3 characters long (since you didn't give rules for expected output if it is not), this is the *fastest* way to do it:

```
String prodPath = path + '/' +
                  prodName.charAt(0) + '/' +
                  prodName.charAt(1) + '/' +
                  prodName.charAt(2) + '/' +
                  prodName + '/';
```

Normally, `char + char` is integer addition, not string concatenation, but since the first value is a `String`, and the `+` operator is left-associative, all `+` operators are string concatenations, not numeric additions.

Comment: mine took this long: 2730 ns
yours took this long: 12629 ns - After a warmup

Comment: @ScaryWombat If yours use `"/"` I get same performance. With `'/'` yours is faster (40ns vs 55ns). I just realized that since `path` is a `String`, the problem of `char + char` becoming integer math doesn't apply, so I can use `'/'` too and get same performance, in a less wordy way.

Comment: indeed less wordy.  I think all this proves is that I need a faster computer

Comment: @ScaryWombat i7-6700K 4GHz AlienWare X51 gaming PC. A bit overkill for Java development, but great for gaming.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `String.charAt`

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder (path);
    b.append ('/').append (prodName.charAt (0))
      .append ('/').append(prodName.charAt (1))
      .append ('/').append(prodName.charAt (2))
      .append ('/').append (prodName).append ('/');
```

Comment: If going for the wordy `StringBuilder`, you might as well optimize to use `'/'` instead of `"/"`. Also, you dropped the leading `path` and trailing `/` from the result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex for simple stuff like this. You may save a couple lines, but you loose a lot in readability. Regex usually take some time to understand when reading them.

```
String s = path;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    s += prodName.substring(i,i+1) + "/";
s += prodName
```

Comment: I always cringe when I see `string += string` in a loop. So why is this *better* than original code in question? It's 4 lines of code, and so is question. Also, you dropped the leading `path` and trailing `/` from the result.

Comment: Quite the opposite, you *gain* readability by using a straightforward regular expression here.

Comment: @Andreas you cringe at the wrong things. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MessageFormat.format()`

```
MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/", baseDir, name.charAt(0), name.charAt(1), name.charAt(2), name);
```

imho i would wrap it for readability,

```
private String getProductionDirectoryPath(String baseDir, String name) {
    return MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/", baseDir, name.charAt(0), name.charAt(1), name.charAt(2), name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No use of a regex, but a simple split over nothing =)

```
String[] firstThree = prodName.split("");
String prodPath = path + "/" + firstThree[0] + "/" + firstThree[1] + "/" + firstThree[2] + "/" + prodName + "/";
```

Another approach is using `charAt()`:

```
String prodPath = path + "/" + prodName.charAt(0) + "/" + prodName.charAt(1) + "/"+ prodName.charAt(2) + "/" + prodName + "/";
```

Comment: Splitting the *entire* string into one-character strings is a bit of overkill, don't you think? For second option, there's no need for `String.valueOf(ch)`, since string concatenation works fine for `char` values. Also, neither option gives original result of leading with `path + "\"` and ending with `"\"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, updated my answer although there's better ones out there. At least it's correct now =)

Answer (score 0):

Positive look ahead can be used

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Calvin";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?=^(\\w)(\\w)(\\w))", "/$1/$2/$3/"));
}
```

O/P:

```
/C/a/l/Calvin
```

Comment: You dropped the leading `path` and trailing `/` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Builder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sb.append("/").append(prodName.charAt(i));
}
sb.append('/').append(prodName);
```

Or you can put all the code in loop:

```
int size = 2;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
        sb.append('/');
    sb.append(prodName.charAt(i)).append("/");
    if (i == size)
        sb.append(prodName);
}
```

Comment: You dropped the leading `path` and trailing `/` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You said *efficient* but you maybe  meant *terse*. I doubt either should be an objective,  so you have a different problem.

Why do you care that this string transformation requires four lines of code? Are you concerned that something that in your mind is one operation ("create transformed string") is spread over four Java operations? You should extract the four lines of Java into their own method. Then, when you read the code where the operation is needed you have one conceptual operation ("create transformed string") corresponding to one Java operation (call a method). You could call the methid `createTransformedString` to make the code even clearer.